# Dynamic proxy_pass in nginx with ports like gitpod

Tags: nginx, proxy

How set dynamic proxy_pass in nginx like `gitpod.com`:

I already have a wildcard certificate

For example, in Gitpod you have a `VM` and if you start a port like `8081`, your URL is:
`https://8081-some-uuid.ws-us02.gitpod.io/`

Following this order of ideas, I would like to configure something like

```
8082.example.com -> http://localhost:8082
8081.example.com -> http://localhost:8081
8080.example.com -> http://localhost:8080
```

**site-enabled/example-com.config**

```
server {
    server_name *.example.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        // how config this??
        proxy_pass http://localhost:(¿dynamic port?);

        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a wildcard name with `server_name`, you could use a regular expression to capture the subdomain part of the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

For example:

```
server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[0-9]{4})\.example\.com$";
proxy_pass http://localhost:$subdomain;
```